# Laravel grouped routes issue

Tags: laravel-4, controller, routes

I try to use routes in Laravel to split backend from frontend. and I wonder how should I group my controllers

using the following

```
// Get the URL segment to use for routing
$urlSegment = Config::get('feeds2go::app.access_url');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
    //$urlSegment = Config::get('feeds2go::app.access_url_admin');
    Route::filter('adminFilter', 'Fefe\Feeds2go\Filters\Admin');
    Route::controller('/posts', 'Fefe\Feeds2go\Controllers\PostsController');
    Route::controller('', 'Fefe\Feeds2go\Controllers\DashController');
});


Route::controller($urlSegment, 'Fefe\Feeds2go\Controllers\SiteController');

/** Include IOC Bindings * */
include __DIR__ . '/bindings.php';
```

when I hit `/admin` the proper controller is getting fired but on `/admin/posts` a wrong controller is getting called `SiteController` instead `PostsController`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can be specific about the routes and apply a route group as follows:

```
    // Admin routes
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|admin'), function()
{
    Route::resource('admin/', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get(//route details here
    //More specific routes here...
});
```

Then, in you filters.php, define the filter:

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    // get current user
    $user = //code to get current user;

    // code to check user permissions, depending on how 
    // you've defined an admin user

    if ( ! adminuser )
    {
        return Redirect::home()
        ->with('flash_message', 'You do not have the appropriate priviliges to view the requested page.');
    }
});
```

Or, you can do it as listed in the docs using a Pattern Based Filter: [enter link description here](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters)

### Pattern Based Filters

You may also specify that a filter applies to an entire set of routes based on their URI.

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    //
});

Route::when('admin/*', 'admin');
```